# How to make the OS schedule disk accesses optimally?

Tags: linux, performance, operating-system

Suppose that a process needs to access the file system in many (1000+) places, and the order is not important to the program logic. However, the order obviously matters for performance if the file system is stored on a (spinning) hard disk.

How can the application programmer communicate to the OS that it should schedule the accesses optimally? Launching 1000+ threads does not seem practical. Does database management software accomplish this, and if so, then how?

**Additional details**: I had a large (1TB+) `mmapped` file where I needed to read 1000+ chunks of about 1KB, each time in new, unpredictable places.

Comment: [..3. Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it..](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @xmojmr It's not homework

Comment: What kind of application needs this? Are you accessing randomly very small chunks of file data?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I added some details

Comment: How likely it is that similar set of "unpredictable places" will be hit within next few minutes and caching the previous results in memory would make sense - versus - no caching is needed and always do direct dirty read?

Comment: So it is not accessing a lot the "file system" (I first understood that you are reading thousands of different files) but accessing randomly a lot a single huge file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel will already reorder the read/write requests (e.g. to fit the spin of a mechanical disk), if they come from various processes or threads. BTW, most of the reads & writes would go to the kernel file system cache, not to the disk.

You might consider using [posix_fadvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/posix_fadvise.2.html) & perhaps (in a separate thread) [readahead(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readahead.2.html). If -instead of [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html)-ing- you use [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) to project some file portion to virtual memory, you might use also [madvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html)

Of course, the file system does not usually guarantee that a sequential portion of a file is physically sequentially located on the disk (and even the disk firmware might reorder sectors). See picture in [Ext2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext2) wikipage, also relevant for [Ext4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4). Some file systems might be better in that respect, and you could tune their block size (at `mkfs` time).

I would not recommend having thousands of threads (only at most a few dozens).

At last, it might worth buying some [SSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive) or some more RAM (for file cache). See http://linuxatemyram.com/

Actual performance would depend a lot on the particular system and hardware.

Perhaps using an indexed file library like [GDBM](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/) or a database library [Sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) (or a real database like PostGreSQL) might be worthwhile! Perhaps have fewer files but bigger ones could help.

BTW, you are `mmap`-ing, and reading small chunk of 1K (smaller than page size of 4K). You could use `madvise` (if possible in advance), but you should try to read larger chunks, since every file access will bring at least a whole page.

You really should benchmark!

Comment: "Of course, the file system does not usually guarantee that a sequential portion of a file is physically sequentially located on the disk" What do you mean exactly? That inside a block sectors are not usually adjacent on disk?

Answer (score 2):

Files and their transactions are cached in various devices in your computer; RAM and the HD cache are the most usual places. The file system driver may also implement IO transaction queues, defragmentation, and error-correction logic that makes things complicated for the developer who wants to control every aspect of file access. This level of complexity is ultimately designed to provide integrity, security, performance, and coordination of file access across all processes of your system.

Optimization efforts should not interfere with the system's own caching and prediction algorithms, not just for IO but for all caches. Trying to second-guess your system is a waste of your time and your processors' time.

Most probably your IO operations and data will stay on caches and later be committed to your storage devices when your OS sees fit.

That said, there's always options like database suites, mmap, readahead mechanisms, and direct IO to your drive. You will need to invest time benchmarking any of your efforts. I advise against multiple IO threads because cache contention will make things even slower than one thread.

Comment: Can you give any details on how the app dev can access those transaction queues? My question was: "How can the programmer communicate to the OS that it should schedule the accesses optimally?"

Comment: I read your question before answering, no need to be rude about it. For the EXT4 and btrfs filesystem, you can access the queues right here, in the kernel: https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs

Comment: I didn't mean to be rude. The way I read it, your answer explains that the OS has the functionality needed to schedule the I/O well (which I knew), but does not explain how an app dev can access it (which was my question). In any case, thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 2):

In the early days when parameters like [Wikipedia: Hard disk drive performance characteristics → Seek time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_disk_drive_performance_characteristics#Seek_time) were very expensive and thus very important, database vendors payed attention to the on-disk data representation and layout as can be seen e.g. in [Oracle8i: Designing and Tuning for Performance → Tuning I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/server.817/a76992/ch20_io.htm).

The important optimization parameters changed with appearance of Solid-state drives (SSD) where the seek time is 0 (or at least constant) as there is nothing to rotate. Some of the new parameters are addressed by [Wikipedia: Solid-state drive (SSD) → optimized file systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive#File_systems_suitable_for_SSDs).

But even those optimization parameters go away with the use of [Wikipedia: In-memory databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-memory_database). The [list of vendors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_in-memory_databases) is pretty long, all big players on it.

So how to schedule your access optimally depends a lot on the use case (1000 concurrent hits is not sufficient problem description) and buying some RAM is one of the options and "*how can the programmer communicate with the OS*" will be one of the last (not first) questions

Comment: You are right, I added some details. Moving everything into RAM is not possible, and 1000+ threads is not practical. (Fabio also pointed out that threads would only slow things down)